# Google+ Sign-in for Android - Google Permissions Activity Result Codes

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, google-signin

I've found out a small issue when working with Google+ Sign for Android and after searching the web (and SO obviously) I'm asking my question out loud to see if anyone has noticed the same.

I'm enabling server-side API access for my app as described 
[here.](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) 
Let me be detailed about what's going on. Take this fragment:

```
Bundle appActivities = new Bundle();
appActivities.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES,
          "<APP-ACTIVITY1> <APP-ACTIVITY2>");
String scopes = "oauth2:server:client_id:<SERVER-CLIENT-ID>:api_scope:<SCOPE1> <SCOPE2>";
String code = null;
try {
  code = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
      this,                                              // Context context
      Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient),  // String accountName
      scopes,                                            // String scope
      appActivities                                      // Bundle bundle
  );

} catch (IOException transientEx) {
  // network or server error, the call is expected to succeed if you try again later.
  // Don't attempt to call again immediately - the request is likely to
  // fail, you'll hit quotas or back-off.
  ...
  return;
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
  // Requesting an authorization code will always throw
  // UserRecoverableAuthException on the first call to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken
  // because the user must consent to offline access to their data.  After
  // consent is granted control is returned to your activity in onActivityResult
  // and the second call to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken will succeed.
  startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), AUTH_CODE_REQUEST_CODE);
  return;
} catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
  // Failure. The call is not expected to ever succeed so it should not be
  // retried.
  ...
  return;
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

See the `UserRecoverableAuthException` and it's comment? Well, that is what I want to talk you about. In that case as you can see, another activity is started and it begins a flow where you have to accept the permissions the app is requesting. As you can see the `startActivityForResult` method is being used. What I observed is that `Activity.RESULT_OK` is being returned when the users accepts to give the permissions but `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` is returned both when an error/crash occurs or when the user simply refuses to give permission and cancels the flow.

So here is (YEAH, FINALLY!) my question... How can I difference one case (error/crash) from the other (possible user flow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after fighting a while with this I think I found a solution. I don't know if it's the right way to do it, but I thought I should share it, so here it goes.

we have the `onActivityresult` method that the activity doing the login/sign in should implement.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     (...)
}
```

What I thought (after a thinking a while, and later confirmed) was that the `Intent data` parameter should have some kind of clue or info about what kind of error or result is being returned. After inspecting it little bit I found that in the case of the user denying the permissions for the app, this intent had an Extra String with key `Error` and value `UserCancel`. So that's what I ended up using to distinguish one case from the other. Hope it helps!

```
   data.getExtraString("Error"); // This should have the value "UserCancel" when the user    
                                 // refused to give the permissions required by the app.
```

Please note that the `data` intent may not always offer this ExtraString, and in fact may be `null` for some calls of `onActityResult`, so you should check `if (data != null)` before using this.